# How to create/refresh and show a Report Viewer using AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i'm trying to refresh a report viewer previously placed in code but it's is static because i need to refresh it from a static method and the method is static due to ajax, if is not static, ajax can't call it, this is my code
Ajax function

```
var paramReport = {
        fupId : idFup,
        version : idVersion
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FormHojaDeVidaProyecto.aspx/loadReporteFup",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(paramReport),
        complete: function() {
            toastr.success("Report Viewer llamado correctamente", "Informacion", {
                "timeOut": "0",
                "extendedTImeout": "0"
            });
        }
    })
```

And the code in the .cs file

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static void loadReporteFup(string fupId, string version)
        {
            Boolean haypar = false;
            ReporteFUPv = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer();
            ReporteFUPv.Width = 500;
            ReporteFUPv.Height = 500;
            ReporteFUPv.Reset();
            //ReporteFUPv.KeepSessionAlive = true;
            //ReporteFUPv.AsyncRendering = true;
            ReporteFUPv.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials("pass", "pass", "user");
            ReporteFUPv.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;

            ReporteFUPv.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(".../ReportServer");

            List<ReportParameter> parametro = new List<ReportParameter>();

            parametro.Add(new ReportParameter("pFupID", fupId, true));
            haypar = true;
            parametro.Add(new ReportParameter("pVersion", version.Trim(' '), true));
            haypar = true;

            ReporteFUPv.PromptAreaCollapsed = true;
            ReporteFUPv.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/...";

            if (haypar)
            {
                ReporteFUPv.ServerReport.SetParameters(parametro);
                ReporteFUPv.LocalReport.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

The method executes all right but in the browser nothing happens, the report viewer appears in blank totally, i have changed the credentials and web uri for security, i have another page where the report viewer works well, the unique change is... there the both method and report viewer entity aren't static

Answer (score 1):

don't grasp why because something is static, you THEN need/want/will/suggest to use some static method.

All ajax calls to a web page are static because the controls and web page is still setting on the user's desktop, and hence no use of controls in code behind.

Seems to me if you want to filter the report, then use code behind to supply the RDL report a dataset from code.

This of course will involve a post-back (but so what??? - why bother/worry about some post-back???). All ajax calls/methods HAVE to be static, or of couse can call code that typcial creates instances of objects you need. What you do NOT HAVE of course is the page class and controls, since as noted, the page is still sitting on the user's desktop.

I would modify the XML (the RDL) of the report, remove the data source from the markup, and then simply add the dataset (use a .net datatable variable), and set the reports source to that data from code behind.

The code behind will/can look like this:

```
    {
        DataTable dt = RstD("SELECT * FROM Fighters"); // add filter and paramters as you need

        // add this data table to the report.
        ReportDataSource rpData = new ReportDataSource("dFighters", dt);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rpData);
        // ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }

    DataTable RstD(string sSQL)
    {
        DataTable ds = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(sSQL, mycon))
            {
                mycon.Open();
                ds.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

The solution is to edit (and remove) the data source of the report, and supply from code behind with any filter(s) you want. Assuming this is a client side (not sql server based) report, then this is certainly possible